# Why Android DecimalFormat Found String Value?

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I use DecimalFormat in Anroid Studio. I had a double value and I want to decimalformat. But, when I give double value in decimalformat; they said: "Found String Value". But, it's a double value. I try convert to string but it doesn't work. What can I do?

```
   double lat = (latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI);
   DecimalFormat DF = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
   Double latlast = DF.format(lat);
```

Comment: Who is "they" that you refer to? If there was an error, please give the entire stacktrace here

Comment: They mean is logcat.

Comment: What is `latpoint`?

Comment: @Nexevis, It is last value with decimalformat on lat.

Comment: as mentioned below , `DF.format(lat)` returns `String` .. if you want to keep the double value just use `Double.valueOf(DF.format(lat))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DF.format(lat)` is returning a `String`, you cannot format a `Double` to anything you want.
A *double* cannot hold all trailing zeroes for example:

```
System.out.println((double) 1.0000);  //Will print 1.0
```

To print it to anything you want you must print it as a String:

```
System.out.println("1.0000"); //Will print 1.0000
```

Which is why `.format` returns a `String` rather than a double.

Change the final line to this:

`String latlast = DF.format(lat);`

EDIT: Try this instead if you want to *truncate* a decimal place to 6 digits.

```
double lat = (latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI);
double latFloor = Math.floor(lat * 1000000) / 1000000; //6 decimal places
```

Comment: I try it and I add this: "Double A = value.of(latlast);". But app is crashed.

Comment: This does not make sense to do (convert it to String then back again), but if you insist try using `Double A = Double.valueOf(latlast);`.  Converting it back will not retain the format you declared, if you want to keep the format you must use it as a `String`

Comment: But, I must use LatIng and it want to double value.

Comment: Formatting is for displaying or using it as a `String`, if you need the double value just use the `lat` value, why would you need to format how many decimals it has first?  Format the final output when you need it to be displayed.

Comment: Because, lat value is return "4.12345678912" but I want "4.123456"

Comment: Why do you need cut off the precision?

Comment: But, Google Maps API return "4.12345678912", but need "4.123456"  for matches.

Comment: Do you always need 6 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat.format(double val)` returns `String`, not `Double`.

```java
double lat = (latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI);
DecimalFormat DF = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
String latlast = DF.format(lat);
```

Comment: I try it and I add this: "Double A = value.of(latlast);". But app is crashed.

Comment: Why would you format a `double` value to string and then convert it back to `double`?

Comment: But, I must use LatIng and it want to double value.

Comment: Then why can't you use the `lat` variable?

Comment: Because, lat value is return "4.12345678912" but I want "4.123456"

Comment: Just round the `lat` using `Math.floor()`, e.g. to round to 2 decimal places: `Math.floor(lat * 100.0) / 100.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format double into double with some requirements then you can convert it again because

```
double lat = (latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
String format1 = format.format(ad);
```

this code returns formatted double into string form.

So you have to convert it again into double again with this

```
double number = Double.parseDouble(format1);
```